# Best choice for 5k request spikes on dynamic server

Tags: apache, server, load-balancing

I am building a backend that is supposed to handle 5k request spikes. The application is a photo sharing app that uses SQL for database, php to handle requests and x-sendfile to send the images to user. What is the best setup server wise? 
Now i have build a HAProxy load balancer to two apache servers who have a shared folder to access images and a database server. 4 servers in total. We may install memcached to save some processing. Will this hold? Is this a good setup? Do you have any suggestions on improvements or better solutions?

Comment: No idea if it will work. You need to load test your particular application to know if it will work or not and potentially iron out any performance bottleneck. The setup you mentioned sounds sensible... so you only need to test. One suggestion, do stress and soak tests of you app, as both highlight different issues

Comment: thanks for the answer Augusto. I found loader.io that stress tests good for free.